# Write to multiple csv using glob

Tags: python, pandas, csv, glob

I am working with lots of csv files and need to add column. I tried glob, for example:

```
import glob

filenames = sorted(glob.glob('./DATA1/*2018*.csv'))
filenames = filenames[0:10]

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for f in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, index_col=None)
    df.columns = ['Date','Signal','Data','Code']
 #this is what I should add to all csv files   
    df["ID"] = df["Data"].str.slice(0,2)
```

and I need a way to save the file back to csv (not concatenated) with different name such as "file01edited.csv" after I add the column to each csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) with `f-string`s for change file names:

```
for f in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, names=['Date','Signal','Data','Code'], index_col=None)
 #this is what I should add to all csv files   
    df["ID"] = df["Data"].str.slice(0,2) 
    #python 3.6+
    df.to_csv(f'{f[:-4]}edited.csv', index=False)
    #python bellow 3.6
    #df.to_csv('{}edited.csv'.format(f[:-4]), index=False)
```

Comment: Tried these but keep getting error: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5 elements, new values have 4 elements. May I know what's the f[:-4] stands for?

Comment: @npm - it remove `.csv` from file name - `file01.csv` to `file01` and then added `edited.csv` for `file01edited.csv`

Comment: @npm - but your error means there are 5 columns in some file, so `df.columns = ['Date','Signal','Data','Code']` or `names=['Date','Signal','Data','Code']` failed